# Strange Firebug Error That Includes the doctype

Tags: html, firebug

Theres a strange syntax error in firebug. I thought it was the doctype and have changed the doctype several times but no luck

any ideas

http://bootcamp.online-marketing-dallas.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you cite has a syntax error:

unterminated string literal
http://bootcamp.online-marketing-dallas.com/
Line 16

try { console.log('); } catch (e) {}

This syntax error is not in Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

There are some javascript resources that are no available:

superfish, supersubs, etc.

That make FF complains about the script tag src attribute.